# jQuery file upload - get the "Open" event from the dialog window

Tags: jquery, file-upload, dialog

Does anyone know how can I find out when the "Open" button was clicked in the dialog window of the file upload?

I just want to do some checks once this has happened (validation etc.) and then perform the upload automatically.

Also - I don't want to use any plugins as I know there are a few.

Comment: Ok - I've figured it out myself - simply use .change() function - like so:

$("#element").change(function() { // do something here });

Comment: You should resolve your own question with an answer so it disappears from the "unanswered" filter list.

Answer (score 1):

But the file dialog opens upon clicking on the `<input type="file" />` field.

So you could even do..

```
$("#element").click({
   //dialog opening now
});
```

`.change()` would trigger only if you actually select something that differs from the previous value, if I'm not wrong.